# How can I add verification to my MVC field?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following defined:

```
public class Menu
{
    [DisplayName("Control")]
    public int Control { get; set; }
```

Using it like this:

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Control, new { id = "control" })
```

Is it possible for me to specify a range for the order? I would like the order to be a 
number between 0 and 999.

Also is it possible for me to make the textbox that gets created just have space for three
characters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Is it possible for me to specify a range for the order? I would like the order to be a number between 0 and 999.
```

use [RangeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679255.aspx)

```
[DisplayName("Control")]
[Range(0, 99, ErrorMessage = "{0} must be between {1} and {2}")]
public int Control { get; set; }
```

For the second question

```
Also is it possible for me to make the textbox that gets created just have space for three characters?
```

use [StringLengthAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute.aspx)

```
[StringLength(3, ErrorMessage="{0} must be {1} characters"]
[DisplayName("Control")]
[Range(0, 99, ErrorMessage = "{0} must be between {1} and {2}")]
public int Control { get; set; }
```

You can also specify a minumun chars length if you want

```
[StringLength(10, minimumLength=5, ErrorMessage="{0} must be between {1} and {2} characters"]
public int Control { get; set; }
```

Comment: My mistake I pasted the wrong link for the StringLengthAttribute. I have updated my answer with the correct link and a sample with minimum length

Answer (score 3):

for range you can use this

```
 public class Menu
    {
        [DisplayName("Control")]
        [Range(0, 999)]
        public int Control { get; set; }
    }
```

and for only three space use this

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Control, new { id = "control",maxlength="3" })
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use **Range** annotation in this case.

```
public class Menu
{
    [DisplayName("Control")]
    [Range(0, 999, ErrorMessage = "Control should be between 0 and 999")]
    public int Control { get; set; }
}
```

Yeah, and for length of textbox

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Control, new { id = "control", maxlength="3" })
```